# Null Pointer Error while doing "alter table table_name drop partition(part_column < value)" on Hive CLI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a spark job (Scala) which writes time-series data onto Hadoop over which there is an external table in Hive.

The table is partitioned by multiple columns and one of the columns (`circle`) has spaces in its values(eg `"Punjab and Rajasthan"`).

Within the spark job when I try to do

```scala
sparksession.sql("""
alter table table_name 
drop if exists partition(creation_time < latestcreationtime)
"""
)
```

I get an Illegal Character Exception of hive metastore, stack trace is attached. I get the same in hive CLI, looks as Hive is unable to read spaces.

> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> MetaException(message:Illegal character in path at index 131:
> /user/optimus/rohit/hive_dump/c360/version=v1.28/set_name=d_si/creation_time=1610994976/compaction_flag=U/si_lob=DTH/circle=Andaman
> and Nicobar Islands);

Answer (score 0):

1.Try dropping and recreating the table
2.Your data might have some issue, what is the underlying data type and table type?